# Create random series of numbers for iOS app

Tags: objective-c, ios, random

I need to get random numbers that are uniform distributed. 
The issue is I need every time the app start to check for some MAX number and then go randomly on all the numbers from 0 to MAX without passing twice on same number (till a round up).

Now I'm using: arc4random()%maxNumber

But that really problematic because I get lots on return even 3 times on same number in a row.

Please help.

Comment: A series of random numbers by definition will have some repeats...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I finally did:

```
-(NSInteger)getNextRandomNumber :(NSInteger)maxNumber{

if (indexSet == nil){
    indexSet = [[NSMutableIndexSet alloc] init];
}
if ([indexSet count] >= maxNumber){
    [indexSet init];
}

NSInteger randomGen = arc4random_uniform(maxNumber);
BOOL foundNumber = FALSE;

while (!foundNumber) {
    if ([indexSet containsIndex:randomGen]){
        randomGen = arc4random_uniform(maxNumber);

    }else{
        [indexSet addIndex:randomGen];
        foundNumber = TRUE;
    }
}

return randomGen;
}
```

If you use it pay attention to releasing the object, Also, I think I might miss one number (not sure) on my case it doesn't matter so...

Comment: I am getting error message indexSet unused variable!
Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

1) Get random number

2) While (number is in used set) number = (number + 1) % MAX

3) Add number to used set

This is a standard algorithm for getting unique random numbers

Comment: I don't want to have a use set, I saw there is a way doing that with nextDouble but I can't figure out how to custom Max random beforehand so I would never "cut" it to a number I saw already.

Comment: arc4random_uniform() will give you a random number between 0 and your max (non-inclusive) but it won't prevent repeats.  If it did, it wouldn't be random.  No idea what you mean by "nextDouble"

Comment: @Idan: nextDouble is Java, not Obj-C.

Comment: If you don't want to have a use set, but also don't want to have repeating doubles, it looks like you want the system to have a use set for you. This is not available, so make your own use set and go with borrrden